# Why isn't this function fast when we collect result from async call?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

```
const services = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

async function foo(service) {

    // function to get one jobUrl data called by map later on
    const getJob = async ({ url: jobUrl }) => {
        const response = await fetch(jobUrl, { headers: headers });
        const { result, timestamp: timeStamp } = await response.json();
        if (result === 'SUCCESS') {
            return { jobUrl, timeStamp };
        }
    };

    // Find the list of jobs for a service
    let url = `http://example.com`;
    const response = await fetch(url, { method: 'POST', headers: headers });
    const { jobs } = await response.json();

    const unfiltered = await Promise.all(jobs.map(getJob));
    const successful = unfiltered.filter(v => v);

    let latestJob = successful.sort((obj1, obj2) => obj2.timeStamp - obj1.timeStamp)[0].jobUrl;
    let arr = latestJob.split('/');
    let recent = { service: service, job: arr[arr.length - 2] };
    console.log(recent);
    // return recent; 
}
```

When I run the following piece of code it takes only 4 seconds for finding the latest job.

```
for (const service of services) {
    foo(service);
}
```

Whereas, when I run the following piece of code it takes 15-16 seconds for finding the latest job. For this I uncomment the `return recent;` line of code in the last line of function `foo` and comment out the `console.log(recent)` line.

```
const latest = [];
for (const service of services) {
    latest.push(await foo(service));
}
```

My understanding is that for the second piece of code since we are waiting for all the async calls to finish it takes longer. If that is the case, is there a way to speed this up?

Comment: You make a bunch of calls and wait for each one to complete before doing the next and you wonder why it takes awhile? either you need to figure out why your requests calls take so long or you need to run them in parallel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use `Promise.all` or `Promise.allSettled`.

That way you can pass an array of async functions (promises) and await them. That way, functions are not running sequentially but async.